# print string to file , why extra bits?

Tags: c++, string, file, printing, visual-c++-2010

I am using VisualC++ 2010,
I have a big string 9600000 bytes that I want to print

When I write it to a file the file size is bigger 9 957 891 bytes. Why ?

I cheched the file size in debug mode so I am sure that it is 9600000

```
ofstream output_asci("output.bin");
output_asci<<the_string;
output_asci.close();
```

Comment: Don't know. Is there newlines in the file? If so, they would be translated from `'\n'` to `'\r','\n'` on a Windows system, to match the traditional newline in a Windows file.

Comment: it is because the system adds a few invisible-to-the-user things to help it comprehend with the file.

Comment: @Infested: I don't think so (unless you mean the carriage return that goes with the linefeed to make up the newline).

Comment: @MatsPetersson virtual memory, frames, pages etc etc.

Comment: Sorry, but not in a file, right?

Comment: @MatsPetersson correct, but the system saves things on the file because of the above.

Comment: @Infested: Not that I've ever seen in my 27 years of programming. Files contain what you write to them. Nothing else. The C runtime will convert newlines, but if you write 16 bytes to a file (no newlines), the file will contain 16 bytes, no more, no less. Of course the ACTUAL space taken on the disk may be bigger, because most filesystems have some block-size that it gets rounded up to [and in really old filesystems, there wasn't a count of number of bytes in the file, so the file would have to have a end-marker]

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/

try adding the flag `ios::binary` as an argument to `ofstream::open`, I do think this will work but I have not tested it.

Comment: Depends on if the file is supposed to be a "binary" or "text" type of file. I tried asking if there are newlines in the file, but no reply yet. If there are newlines, that would explain why the file is different size. If the file is meant to be a text-file, then writing it as binary will just make it useless (albeit "the right size")

Comment: It is perfectly ok to use binary mode to write strings, as long as the string has all the content you need to write in raw data(encoding properly set) [example](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=h1PVGRY2)

Comment: Yes, but it won't then "work" as a text file in other applications that expect a newline to be CR+LF, and if that is the original intention [we still don't know that, since the OP hasn't come back with "yes, I want a text file" or "no, I don't want a text file"].

Comment: Aha! Sorry I misunderstood, OP could handle CR LF himself if the default OS behavior is not what he wants then

Comment: Yes, but if the OP wants to output a ~9.6MB file that OP can open in Wordpad or some such, using text and regular C-style line endings will be the "right" thing to do. My original comment is simply that "This may not actually be what the OP wants". Making it binary so that it's the right size isn't helping much if it's unreadable...